# Why do embedded Jetty examples do server.dump(System.err)?

Tags: jetty, embedded-jetty

All the examples of embedded Jetty I see do `server.dump(System.err)`.  I can't find any docs on what that does or why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you see `server.dump(System.err)` this is a dump of the state of the `Server` object to the `System.err` console appendable.

Jetty operates on a `LifeCycle` model, where every component can be started and stopped and has the ability to track its state.

The `Server` object is a specialized `ContainerLifeCycle` which operates like all other `LifeCycle` objects but also has child beans that follow the `LifeCycle` behaviors.

The call `server.dump(System.err)` is actually the [`ContainerLifeCycle.dump(Appendable)`](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/javadoc/current/org/eclipse/jetty/util/component/ContainerLifeCycle.html#dump(java.lang.Appendable)) call for the `Server`.

This top level Server dump is called `The Jetty Dump Tool`.
See https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-dump-tool.html for details, including a sample output.